# Does pyodbc have an execute scalar function

Tags: python, pyodbc

Does pyodbc have an execute scalar function?

something like executescalar on the sql lib in .net?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think so, but [sqlalchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org) does (apart from using the ORM etc., it can also be used as a handy higher level interface to DB API libraries). As an example:

```
import sqlalchemy

# using mssql as an example because sqlalchemy uses pyodbc as the default driver for MS Sql Server
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("mssql://myserver/mydb")
# first column of first row is returned
username = engine.scalar("select username from users where userid = 1")
```

Answer (score 8):

The pyodbc cursor has a [fetchone()](http://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor) method.

```
cursor.execute("select user_name from users where user_id=?", userid)
row = cursor.fetchone()
if row:
    print row.user_name 
    # or print row[0]
```

Comment: Why has this got 5 upvotes, using a cursor for a single return value is overhead?

Comment: @JeremyThompson - not sure what you mean? All SQL is executed with a db cursor in pyodbc.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify the `pyodbc` call like this:

```py
name = cursor.execute("select user_name from users where user_id=?", userid).fetchval()
```

because

> **fetchval()**
>
> Returns the first column of the first row if there are
> results

and

> **execute(sql, *parameters)**
>
> Prepares and executes a SQL statement, returning the Cursor object itself

Comment: *This* is the correct answer for vanilla pyodbc.